# Geb cannot see slider that's off the page using an interact block

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm trying to access a menu slider but by the time it would receive the click the slider is off the page. The only work around I have found is to put a Thread.sleep in which I want to avoid using.  Is there another way?

def "Step 5: Can go to the Spanish page"() {
    given:
    at DotComPage

```
when:                                          
waitFor {usFlagButtonSpanish.displayed}        
interact {                                     
    Thread.sleep(3000)                         
    moveToElement(usFlagButtonSpanish)         
}                                              
usFlagButtonSpanish.click()                    

then:                                          
Thread.sleep(3000)                             
waitFor { MarketLanguageSelectorEsUs }         
Thread.sleep(9000)
```

}

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Did you mean to post it on this site (we're dedicated to questions about Apple hardware, software or services - incl. the use of 3rd party hardware/software with Apple products). You may want to take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more clarification. If you can edit your post (incl. tags) to fit within our scope, great! If not, perhaps one of the [other SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) is better suited.

Comment: Thank you! I actually did not mean to post it on this site and not sure how that happened.  I meant to post it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test is waiting for the usFlagButtonSpanish to be displayed. You can likely resolve your issue by changing

```
waitFor {usFlagButtonSpanish.displayed}
```

to

```
waitFor {usFlagButtonSpanish}
```